# How can Android application access a centralized database

Tags: android, database, web-services

I am working on an application which has large amount of data in a database. I know that it wont be feasible for me to package this huge database along with the app. I can only think of setting up a central database, so that the app can access it. I am new to android. I thought about using web-services or a http webpage request.

any suggestions for this?

thanks,
Naveen

Comment: yes, web services are quite often employed for this. your question is too broad IMO (no specific use case, no code sample, plenty of possible answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, be familiar with the topics outlined in the Data Storage Developer's Guide.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html